# ItextSharp html to pdf with signature

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I would like to generate a pdf from html and have signature blocks in it.  The html can be in any format, but it will sometimes be 1 page and other times it might be 50 pages.  The signatures will be the only inputs on the page.  An example of the html could be.

```
<div>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?  I am currently using ItextSharp to generate the pdf.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"signature blocks"*? Signature form fields for digital signatures? Or some other electronic signature?

Comment: Yes, signature form fields

Answer (score 1):

A combination of techniques will yield the result you want.

1. use pdfHTML (iText7 add-on) that converts HTML (HTML5 + CSS3) to PDF
2. you can add custom tags and handlers for those tags. You could make one that injects a signature formfield
3. use iText to digitally sign the PDF document

Short example of digital signatures:

```
public void sign(String src, String dest,
             Certificate[] chain,
             PrivateKey pk, String digestAlgorithm, String provider,
             PdfSigner.CryptoStandard subfilter,
             String reason, String location)
    throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
// Creating the reader and the signer
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest), false);
// Creating the appearance
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance()
        .setReason(reason)
        .setLocation(location)
        .setReuseAppearance(false);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(36, 648, 200, 100);
appearance
        .setPageRect(rect)
        .setPageNumber(1);
signer.setFieldName("sig");
// Creating the signature
IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
IExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
signer.signDetached(digest, pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, subfilter);
}
```

Short example of pdfHTML:

```
public void createPdf(String src, String dest, String resources) throws IOException {
    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dest);

        WriterProperties writerProperties = new WriterProperties();
        //Add metadata
        writerProperties.addXmpMetadata();

        PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(outputStream, writerProperties);

        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
        pdfDoc.getCatalog().setLang(new PdfString("en-US"));
        //Set the document to be tagged
        pdfDoc.setTagged();
        pdfDoc.getCatalog().setViewerPreferences(new PdfViewerPreferences().setDisplayDocTitle(true));

        //Set meta tags
        PdfDocumentInfo pdfMetaData = pdfDoc.getDocumentInfo();
        pdfMetaData.setAuthor("Samuel Huylebroeck");
        pdfMetaData.addCreationDate();
        pdfMetaData.getProducer();
        pdfMetaData.setCreator("iText Software");
        pdfMetaData.setKeywords("example, accessibility");
        pdfMetaData.setSubject("PDF accessibility");
        //Title is derived from html

        // pdf conversion
        ConverterProperties props = new ConverterProperties();
        FontProvider fp = new FontProvider();
        fp.addStandardPdfFonts();
        fp.addDirectory(resources);//The noto-nashk font file (.ttf extension) is placed in the resources

        props.setFontProvider(fp);
        props.setBaseUri(resources);
        //Setup custom tagworker factory for better tagging of headers
        DefaultTagWorkerFactory tagWorkerFactory = new AccessibilityTagWorkerFactory();
        props.setTagWorkerFactory(tagWorkerFactory);

        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream(src), pdfDoc, props);
        pdfDoc.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

More information at http://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML

Comment: That looks like a good solution, but I am not finding a way to 'injects a signature formfield'. How do I make an IPropertyContainer for the return of ITagWorker.GetElementResult from a PdfSignatureFormField ?